# como pasar los valores por medio de un button de un TextArea a otro TextArea en la misma pagina en ASP

Tags: asp.net, .net

como pasar los valores por medio de un button de un TextArea a otro TextArea  en la misma pagina en ASP

Comment: Por favor aclara tu pregunta con un __[mcve]__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el Html tienes esto:

```
<textarea runat="server" id="textarea1"></textarea>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <textarea runat="server" id="textarea2"></textarea>
```

en el servidor esto:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textarea1.Value = textarea2.Value;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
      <asp:TextBox id="TextArea1" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
    <asp:TextBox id="TextBox2" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
```

y del lado del code-behind

> ```
>  protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextArea1.Text))
>         {
>             TextBox2.Text = TextArea1.Text;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Las 2 respuestas me sirvieron! Muchas gracias ahora mi problema es el siguiente : por ej el textArea1 me piden que no le ponga el runat=server. del lado code behind no me agarra la etiqueta(el nombre del id) como lo puedo capturar y que me imprima en el textArea2. Desde ya se los agradesco